# error message Install-Package Microsoft.Graph

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, nuget-package

I'm getting this error when trying to install Microsoft.Graph via Package Manager Console: (I'm using Visual Studio Express 2015 for Web, Windows 10 pro- NET 4.5).

> Attempting to gather dependencies information for package 'Microsoft.Graph.1.6.2' with respect to project 'WebApp_Calendar', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5'
>   Install-Package : An error occurred while retrieving package metadata for 'Microsoft.Identity.Client.1.1.0-preview' from source 
>   'C:\Users\admin\Desktop\docs\Repo_Asp\dotnet-tutorial\WebApp_Calendar\packages'.
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + Install-Package Microsoft.Graph
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand>

Can you help me please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> you need to go through Dependencies

**.NETFramework 4.5**

```
Microsoft.Graph.Core (>= 1.6.2)

Newtonsoft.Json (>= 6.0.1 && < 11.0.0)

System.Net.Http (>= 4.3.1)
```

**.NETStandard 1.1**
    Microsoft.Graph.Core (>= 1.6.2)

```
NETStandard.Library (>= 1.6.0)

Newtonsoft.Json (>= 9.0.1 && < 11.0.0)

System.Net.Http (>= 4.3.1)
```

> Go through Documentation 
>   https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Graph

Answer (score -1):

`Install-Package Microsoft.Graph -Version 1.21.0` is stable for .net 4.5.
The rest of the versions of the above packages are for 4.6 or 4.6.1